# Not getting recordId in URL generated from lightning-navigation

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components

On button click on parent LWC component, i am calling lightning-navigation to call child component. I am passing recordID in the attributes as below -

```
<template>
<lightning-button label="CallChild" title="CallChild" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

JS -

```
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";
     connectedCallback() {
        this.redirectchildcomponent = {
          type: "standard__component",
          attributes: {
            componentName: "c__ChildComp",
            recordId: this.recordId
          }
        };
        this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl](this.redirectchildcomponent).then(
          url => (this.url = url)
        );
      }

    handleClick() {
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](this.redirectchildcomponent);
    }
```

After button click i am getting the following url

```
https://XXXXXXXX.lightning.force.com/lightning/cmp/c__ChildComp
```

i am not getting recordid in the URL. And how to capture recordId in the child component to pass it Apex.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From docs, to [Add Query Parameters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_add_params_url), you will need to utilize `state` attribute here.

> To add query parameters to the URL, update the `PageReference.state` property. The navigation service uses a  `PageReference` to generate a URL. The key-value pairs of the `state` property are serialized to URL query parameters.

So your page reference declaration should look like as below (you can find more on the documentation link)

```
this.redirectchildcomponent = {
      type: "standard__component",
      attributes: {
        componentName: "c__ChildComp",
      },
      state: {
        c__recordId: this.recordId
      }
};
```

*Note*:  I haven't tested this out myself, but based on the docs, this should work.

Comment: Thank u Jayant.. It worked.. Just figuring out how to retrieve the recordId in child component

Comment: I would imagine having a public property named `recordId` in your child component should resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

In lightning, I had to do this to retrieve the recordId

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    
    
    var pageReference = component.get("v.pageReference");
    console.log('pagereference = '+pageReference);
    if (pageReference){
        console.log('pageReference exists');
        console.log('pagereference.state = '+pageReference.state);
        if (pageReference.state.c__recordId){
            var coId = pageReference.state.c__recordId;
            console.log('Id in doInit of CompanyLocator ='+coId);
        }//if recordId
        
    }//pageReference

}//doInit
```

})